# assigning different colors to dots based on value extracted from excel

Tags: python

I am relatively new to python programming and I want to create a map of the basic flight range in hours to certain airports out of excel data. I want to specify an airport and create dots with different colors based on their distance in hours. I was able to create a [world map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v009Q.png) where I have inserted a single-color dot with certain coordinates, but I do not know how to proceed from there. After I get the data from excel, I started with these libraries:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd
```

Then, I did this:

```
countries=gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,12))
countries.plot(figsize=(20,20), color="lightgrey",ax=ax)
df.plot(x="Longitude", y="Latitude", kind="scatter", c="red", colormap="YlOrRd",ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

I am thinking that basic plotting won't be enough for my project. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What are you using to plot your data? It might help if you provide a minimal example of your code.

Comment: I add the code example and more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a categorical color instead of your defined color (red). Unfortunately you do not show (a sample of) the contents of your dataframe but judging from your opening post I would guess that is  the column that contains the values for distance in hours.

See the [examples of the DataFrame.plot function for scatter plots](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/visualization.html#scatter-plot), especially the example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(50, 4), columns=["a", "b", "c", "d"])
df["species"] = pd.Categorical(
    ["setosa"] * 20 + ["versicolor"] * 20 + ["virginica"] * 10
)
df.plot.scatter(x="a", y="b", c="species", cmap="viridis", s=50);
```

**Note: this is only available since pandas 1.3.0**